# Reorder Multi Dimensional Array using Custom Keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => one 
            [mp3] => 1.mp3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => two 
            [mp3] => 2.mp3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => three
            [mp3] => 3.mp3
        )

)
```

And I have another array with index to sort array`(1,0,2)` ,So With these I want following

```
 Array
     (

         [0] => Array(
             [text] => two[mp3] => 2. mp3
         )

         [1] => Array(
             [text] => one[mp3] => 1. mp3
         )

         [2] => Array(
             [text] => three[mp3] => 3. mp3
         )

     )
```

I googled and Found Few solutions on stackoverflow , But None seems to be successful for me

```
$order=array(1,0,2);
$orderedarray = array_merge(array_flip($order),$myarr);
$myarr = $orderedarray;

print_r($myarr);
```

Which outputs following

```
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => Array
        (
            [text] => one 
            [mp3] => 1.mp3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [text] => two 
            [mp3] => 2.mp3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [text] => three
            [mp3] => 3.mp3
        )

)
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php).

```
$order =[1,0,2];
array_multisort($myarr, $order);

Var_dump($myarr);
```

https://3v4l.org/cCT9d

Comment: this is much better solution.+1

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks!